# Unable to send emails using mailgun

Tags: mailgun

I have followed the instructions of the mailgun, including dots and commas. I installed composer successfully. My domain name is also verified so I wanted to use API for sending emails.

I created a simple application for testing if emails are going or not.

here is the code of sample php application:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

$mg = new Mailgun("key-********************************");
$domain = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mailgun.************.com/messages";

$mg->sendMessage($domain,
    array(
        'from'    => 'noreply@********.com',
        'to'      => '********@hotmail.com',
        'subject' => 'The mailgun is awesome!',
        'text'    => 'It is so simple to send a message.'));


echo "done";
?>
```

I get internal server error 500 when  I run this file.

When  I change the $domain to "mailgun.*****.com" I get emails but in junk folder

I am confused what is happening here.. no apparent fault..

May be some expert will be able to help me out here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$domain` has to be the same as entered in your settings.

i.e. the domain is `mg.domain.com` in your mailgun account,
your `$domain` is `domain.com`.
Also your `from` has to be `[anything]@domain.com`, to be accepted.